# Spring hibernate - Many to one relationships not working with multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have created a class call Comment which will have a relationship with two classes: House and User. The house and user entites are already in my database and the house already has a one to many relationship with a user but it won't work with a comment. I keep getting an error 404 whenever I try to reload my server and the comment table is not persisted. Below is my code:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @NotBlank(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Size(min = 8, max = 15, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\w{8,}$", groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\S+$", groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Size(min = 8, max = 15, groups = { FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String password;

    @Email(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    @Size(min = 8, max = 60, groups = { PersistenceValidationGroup.class, FormValidationGroup.class })
    private String name;

    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String authority;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private House house;

    public User() {
    }
}
```

And my comment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private House house;

    public Comment() {
    }
}
```

Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give a more specific error? Error 404 is not a persistence error. I suggest you check your server's log files.

Comment: Also, please provide the code where you're attempting to persist your `Comment` instances.